# Enforcing the generic delegate parameter based on a Type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am creating a member in a Class which is something like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<TContract, Task>> ProcessorDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<TContract, Task>>();
```

In the above Dictionary, I want to maintain bindings between a particular type and its associated processors to be run. I want to enforce a constraint that when you add an entry to this dictionary, TContract should be a instance of "Type". For eg:

```
Func<MessageContract,Task> func = ...
ProcessorDictionary.Add(typeof(MessageContract), func)
```

Is this possible? If not what are the alternatives?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but, when I see too many (composed) types in a type declaration, smells like lack of encapulation, or problem declaration. Example: declare "Func<TContract, Task>" as single type like "TaskContractDelegate"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to really enforce it with something similar to a generic constraint. What you can do is "hide" the dictionary behind a generic method (which does support type constraints).

Simply have a class where the dictionary is private and expose a generic method as such:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<TContract, Task>> _processorDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<TContract, Task>>();

public void AddEntry<TContract>(Func<TContract, Task> func)
{
    _processorDictionary[typeof(TContract)] = func;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @l3arnon! That's a nifty solution :)